# Symfony 2 - form with 3 linked entities?

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine

I have a system with 3 linked entities:

Reminder <- Vehicle -> Job

(so one Vehicle can have multiple Reminders and multiple Jobs)

Individually, the forms work well with collections (so you can edit a Vehicle and it's Reminders in a collection), but now I need to create a form where I display the details of a Job, with a list of Reminders linked via the Vehicle. I'm stuck!

Is there a way to access these related entities through the relationship that already exists? I'd like the new form to display the details of a single Job, with a collection of Reminders that are attached to the Vehicle.